# Twilio Client c#

Tags: c#, twilio

I have been using this code to send sms and voice calls for the last few days and now I am getting a weird response. On my recording status app I get the error: `The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.twilio.com'`. I have stripped down my function to a couple basic lines of code and still get the error.

```
TwilioClient.Init(_Twilio.ApiSid, _Twilio.ApiToken);
CallResource call = CallResource.Fetch(pathSid: sCallSid);
if (call != null)
{/*handle error*/}
```

The `sCallSid` string is valid and has a value. the `ApiSid` and `ApiToken` are working as well.

The `'api.twilio.com'` resolved statement has stumped.
Any ideas how to isolate this issue and resolve it?

Comment: Try making the same call with Postman or Fiddler, to make sure it's not your code.

Comment: The error shown there usually means that the it cannot resolve the host name, meaning it doesn't know where to send your request.  Are you sure this is the correct URL to hit?

Comment: Try using `HttpClient` to make a test GET request to the API and see what happens

Comment: I did some more testing and just using the above code (.init and .fetch) it work fine on localhost.  When I run the same either from a browser or through twilio, it fails every time again.